# Use Mysql Variable in Where Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select

i want to write small select something like this

```
select t.id,func(t.name) from table t where func(t.name)>0
```

but i want to call function `func` only once

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You can create your function as DETERMINISTIC which should allow MySQL to cache the results.

Comment: The optimizer will eliminate common subexpressions. Just because you write a function twice does not mean it will be called twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT t.id, func(t.name) AS f
FROM Table AS t
HAVING f > 0
```